# Merge supply-mission and resupply-mission

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, tag-synonyms

The tags [supply-mission](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/supply-mission) and [resupply-missions](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/resupply-missions) are the same thing and they should be synonyms. I don't have the rep to suggest the synonym so hoping some can do it for me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've gone ahead and merged them. Thanks for pointing this out!